# How to render a React Hook State whose type is an Array of Objects?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, javascript-objects, react-hooks

I am trying to render the array of objects stored in a React Hook state, which stores the names and numbers for a phonebook:

```
const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '000-000-0000' },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
  ]); 

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <div>{persons}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However I get the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, number}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I've tried the following:

I thought by creating `<div>` for each index of the array, I can render each individually, rather than rendering the whole array at once, but that does not seem to be the issue.

```
const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '000-000-0000' },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
  ]); 

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <div>{persons.map(person => <div> {person} </div>)}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But when I try that, I get the same error message.

How can I render the objects in the state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're still trying to render an `object`. You need to access it's `properties`

```
const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '000-000-0000' },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
  ]); 

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <div>{persons.map(person => <div key={person.name}> {person.name} </div>)}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see. How come React does not allow you to render objects directly?

Comment: How an `object` should be rendered inside a `html` element? Only primitives... You could try `JSON.stringify()` to render a string representation of the object

Comment: @boxcarcoder the renderer cannot guess how composite types should be displayed.

Comment: I couldn't possibly phrase it better

Answer (score 0):

There is no default renderer for Objects. You can render JSON serialisation of an object, like `<div>{JSON.stringify(persons)}</div>`. But it is likely not what you want to do.

Although the answer above shows how to unfold and render the nested objects, you probably want to set the nested fields eventually and manipulate the state and have it done efficiently. Have a look into [Hookstate](https://github.com/avkonst/hookstate), it is supercharged useState hook which simplifies and speeds up management of complex / nested states. For example here is the similar [demo](https://hookstate.js.org/local-complex-from-documentation). (disclaimer: I am an author of the project)